# wordpress secondary database

Tags: php, wordpress

I couldn't log on WordPress, so I looked in a database on godaddy's phpMyAdmin and tried to update the password using md5. (I didn't back-up the database, and now I'm paying for it).

This caused an error so it wouldn't even bring up the login screen, and gave me a screen saying that the program couldn't connect with the database I edited. The thing is, the db that I edited is not the one associated with the `wp-config.php`, so I can't just try to fix it there, at least not by just changing the password there.

Comment: Pretty hard to say... Perhaps sharing url to your site could help... Which table did you edit and which columns in that table?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The site is tahoecommunitychurch.org. The table is the one marked "wordpress(tahoecommunitychurch.org/)" and these are the types of the rows:wp_commentmeta 
wp_comments
wp_links
wp_options
wp_postmeta
wp_posts Browse
wp_terms
wp_term_relationships
wp_term_taxonomy
wp_usermeta
wp_users     I modified the user_pass in wp_users.

Comment: Where do u get the error? Home page seems 2 b all right :)

Comment: The site is fine, but I just can't sign into wordpress so I can edit it, (Upload sermons and post events and such).  If I put in tahoecommunitychurch.org/wp-admin it brings up a screen that says "Error establishing database connection" and shows the database name that I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out!  Essentially, there were more than one databases linked with this website, however THEY WERE EACH TO DIFFERENT URL EXTENTIONS like /tccnewsite and /wordpress.  I found this out in the wp_options part of each table.
Also, there were two kinds of passwords:  User Passwords, and Database Passwords. User passwords were changed in the table.  Database passwords were changed in goDaddy.
Lastly,  I had to search through all of my wordpress files (in godaddy's file manager) to find the DIFFERENT wp-config.php files for each sub-domain of the site.  Then I could match the Database Password (set in godaddy, not in the database itself) to the password in each wp-config.php.